Continuity and differentiability of ratios of functions
I'm studying for an exam and am stuck on this problem:
Suppose that f and g are continuously differentiable real-valued functions on R such that $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ and $g'(0) \neq 0$. Which of the following statements must be true?
I. The function $f/g$ can be extended to a continuous function in a neighborhood of 0.
II. The function $(f^2 - f)/(2g-g^3)$ can be extended to a continuous function in a neighborhood of 0.
III. The function $f/g$ can be extended to a differentiable function in a neighborhood of 0.
Correct answer: I and II
I believe that I is true because $f/g$ will have a removable discontinuity since the degree of the root 0 in g is one. But I'm not sure how to approach the other two statements. Thank  you!!!

For II, factor $$\frac{f^2 - f}{2g - g^3} = \frac{f}{g}\cdot \frac{f-1}{2-g^2}$$ Since $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(f(x)-f(0))/x}{(g(x)-g(0))/x} = \frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)} = 0$$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-1}{2-g(x)^2} = -\frac12$, then we can extend $(f^2-f)/(2g-g^3)$ continuously to a neighborhood of $0$ by declaring that it equals $0$ at $x = 0$.
To see III is false, consider $f(x) = x|x|$ and $g(x) = x$. Both $f$ and $g$ satisfy the hypotheses but since $f(x)/g(x) = |x|$ away from $0$, $f/g$ has no differentiable extension to a neighborhood of $0$.

Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Everything makes more sense now.
